# Forcing npm to install specific version of a node package which already specified in a child module

Tags: npm, node-modules

I'm developing a npm package (pack_b in the tree structure below) which is built in stable releases and nightly releases. Both `main_app` and `pack_a` is packages that depends on `pack_b`

By specifying the very same version of `pack_b` in both `main_app` and `pack_a` we will resulting in this folder structure:

```
- main_app
  - node_modules
    - pack_a
    - pack_b
```

So far so good, but I would like to be able to use the nightly build of `pack_b` and by specifying nightly build version of `pack_b` in `main_app` will result in the following structure:

```
- main_app
  - node_modules
    - pack_a
      - node_modules
        - pack_b (stable)
    - pack_b (nightly)
```

Unfortunately this will break the way the application works since two versions will be instantiated. I would like to be able to force install the nightly version of `pack_b` and just use that version in all modules like:

```
- main_app
  - node_modules
    - pack_a
    - pack_b (nightly)
```

Is that achievable?

Comment: It's not possible AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

The only way im aware of doing that would be to use the same version(nightly) in both main_app and pack_a.

That's just how npm works, for more info check this out 
https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3-nondet